# Calculator with simple input

Tags: c++, beginner, calculator

This is "my" version of a basic C++ calculator, that requires a single line input (like 1+1) to calculate the result. I have been (self)learning the language for 2 months now. I don't pretend to have invented this code, but I haven't taken the time to search for this variation.

The functions included are:

- Addition: `1 + 1 = 2`

  Input in program: `1+1`
- Subtraction: `1 - 1 = 0`

  Input in program: `1-1`
- Multiplication: `1 * 1 = 1`

  Input in program: `1*1`
- Division: `1 / 1 = 1`

  Input in program: `1/1`
- Exponentiation: `2 ^ 2 = 4`

  Input in program: `2^2`

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Math_Functions
{
private:
    double result;

public:
    double addition(double, double);
    double subtraction(double, double);
    double multiplication(double, double);
    double division(double, double);
    double exponentiation(double, double);
} math;

double Math_Functions::addition(double a, double b)
{
    result = a + b;
    return result;
}

double Math_Functions::subtraction(double a, double b)
{
    result = a - b;
    return result;
}

double Math_Functions::multiplication(double a, double b)
{
    result = a * b;
    return result;
}

double Math_Functions::division(double a, double b)
{
    result = a / b;
    return result;
}

double Math_Functions::exponentiation(double a, double b)
{
    result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        result *= a;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    double a, b;
    string function;
    bool loop = 1;

    while(loop)
    {
        system("CLS");
        cin >> a;
        function = getchar();
        cin >> b;

        switch(function[0])
        {
            case '+' : cout << math.addition(a, b); break;
            case '-': cout << math.subtraction(a, b); break;
            case '*': cout << math.multiplication(a, b); break;
            case '/': cout << math.division(a, b); break;
            case '^': cout << math.exponentiation(a, b); break;
        }
        cout << endl << "Press Any Key to Continue . . . ";
        cin.sync();
        cin.ignore();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up the concept of the `Command Pattern`. It will remove the need for a switch.

Answer (score 10):

If you're about to perform division, you *must* first check for 0 as the given divisor.  To prevent this, it may be best to warn the user, and make sure they input a valid number before proceeding.

For the exponentiation, you can have a "shortcut" by returning 1 instantly if `b` is 0.  There's no need to attempt calculations since anything raised to the 0 power is always 1.  You should also handle negative powers in some way.  The code will break if the user inputs such a value for `b`.  This loop cannot handle all of these possible values.

Comment: Now as I read it it seems so logical it makes me wonder where my mind was when I was writing the code down... Rewriting in process.

Comment: Division by zero in the context of floating point operation is well defined in C++, the possible results are either + or -infinity or NaN (not a number)

Answer (score 9):

#### Avoid `using namespace std`

It's [considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) to do `using namespace std`.

#### Don't use a `string` when a simple `char` is enough

Since `function` must be a single character, there's no need to use a `string` for it and then use `function[0]` in the `switch`. You could use a simple `char`:

```
char function = getchar();
```

#### Use `true` and `false` for booleans

Instead of:

> ```
> bool loop = 1;
> ```

You should write:

```
bool loop = true;
```

However, since the `while` loop in the `main` function never terminates,
the boolean variable is pointless, and you could just write:

```
while (true) {
    // ...
}
```

#### Why is `result` a member variable?

I don't see why `result` is a private variable of the class.
Why not make it a local variable instead?
In fact, most methods don't need a local variable at all and could return the output of their calculation directly, for example:

```
double Math_Functions::addition(double a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}

double Math_Functions::subtraction(double a, double b)
{
    return a - b;
}
```

Comment: Point taken for everything! Thank you very much. Guess I'll have to rewrite all my previous programs with these enlightments.

Answer (score 7):

I am going to suggest couple of changes to your code.

**Providing a clean way to terminate the program**

Your code does not provide a clean way to terminate the program. Once started, you have to terminate the program by pressing the equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, killing the process form the Task Manager, or some such indirect mechanism.

There are lots of ways to terminate a program cleanly. One of the easiest things to do is look for `q` or `Q` as the first character of the input to exit the program.

However, if you allow for such a method, you'll need to change how you receive user input and process them.

Instead of

```
    cin >> a;
    function = getchar();
    cin >> b;
```

you'll need to use:

```
    std::string line;
    std::getline(cin, line);

    // Ignore blank lines.
    if (line.empty() )
    {
        continue;
    }

    // Check for `q` or `Q`. If found, break out of the loop.
    if ( line[0] == `q'` or line[0] == `Q`)
    {
        break;
    }

    // Create a stringstream and extract the data from the line.
    std::istringstream inStream(line);
    inStream >> a;
    inStream >> function;
    inStream >> b;
```

**Dealing with bad input**

If the user provides bad input, whether on purpose or on accident, you are not dealing with it at all. When extracting the `a`, `function`, and `b`, check whether the input stream is still in valid state. If not, print a message and go to the start of the `while` loop.

```
    inStream >> a;
    inStream >> function;
    inStream >> b;

    if ( !inStream )
    {
       std::cerr << "'" << line << "' contains invalid input.\n"
       continue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For exponentiation, you define `b` as `double`. In that case, your code is not in general correct, as you are using a simple integer loop to perform exponentiation. It is *only* valid for nonnegative integer exponents. It could also take a really long time if `b` is a large number. Use

```
return pow(a,b);
```

to allow arbitrary real exponents. The function is in `<cmath>`.

If you really wanted to implement just positive integer exponents, you also didn't use the most sensible solution. Your loop performs `b` multiplications, which can be reduced to `log2(b)` multiplications (basically the number of nonzero bits in `b`) if you use exponentiation by squaring.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring