# Calculator with single line input - follow-up

Tags: c++, beginner

Part 2 of [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78031/calculator-with-simple-input) question. I've rewritten most parts of the code, for the better I hope. The code now has some more logic and less readability.

**Functions included in the calculator:**

- Addition
  User input `2+2` Program output `4`
- Subtraction
  User input `2-2` Program output `0`
- Multiplication
  User input `2*2` Program output `4`
- Division
  User input `2/2` Program output `1`
- Exponentiation
  User input `2^2` Program output `4`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cmath>

class Math_Functions
{
public:
    double addition(double, double);
    double subtraction(double, double);
    double multiplication(double, double);
    void division(double, double);
    void exponentiation(double, double);
} math;

class Results_Handler
{
public:
    void division(std::string);
    void exponentiation(std::string);
} res_handler;

//This function I found somewhere in the deep internet
class Miscellaneous
{
public:
    void Pause()
    {
        std::cout << std::endl << "Press any key to continue . . . ";
        std::cin.sync();
        std::cin.ignore();
    }
    void ClearScreen()
    {
        HANDLE                     hStdOut;
        CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
        DWORD                      count;
        DWORD                      cellCount;
        COORD                      homeCoords = { 0, 0 };

        hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        if (hStdOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return;

        /* Get the number of cells in the current buffer */
        if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdOut, &csbi)) return;
        cellCount = csbi.dwSize.X *csbi.dwSize.Y;

        /* Fill the entire buffer with spaces */
        if (!FillConsoleOutputCharacter(
            hStdOut,
            (TCHAR) ' ',
            cellCount,
            homeCoords,
            &count
            )) return;

        /* Fill the entire buffer with the current colors and attributes */
        if (!FillConsoleOutputAttribute(
            hStdOut,
            csbi.wAttributes,
            cellCount,
            homeCoords,
            &count
            )) return;

        /* Move the cursor home */
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, homeCoords);
    }
} misc;


//Handle the result from division and cout correspondingly
void Results_Handler::division(std::string inPut)
{
    if (inPut != "Error")
    {
        std::cout << inPut;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Come on, you know you can't divide by 0...";
    }
}

//Handle the result from the exponentiation and cout correspondingly
void Results_Handler::exponentiation(std::string inPut)
{
    if (inPut != "Error")
    {
        std::cout << inPut;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "You can't exponentiate by negative numbers.";
    }
}

double Math_Functions::addition(double a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}

double Math_Functions::subtraction(double a, double b)
{
    return a - b;
}

double Math_Functions::multiplication(double a, double b)
{
    return a * b;
}

void Math_Functions::division(double a, double b)
{
    //Dividing by 0 = universe explodes
    if (b == 0)
    {
        res_handler.division("Error");
    }
    else
    {
        double c = a / b;
        std::stringstream result;
        result << c;
        res_handler.division(result.str());
    }
}

void Math_Functions::exponentiation(double a, double b)
{
    //If the number you're exponentiating with is 0 the result is always 1
    if (b == 0)
    {
        res_handler.exponentiation("1");
    }
    //If you're exponentiating with 1 the result is the same number
    else if (b == 1)
    {
        std::stringstream res;
        res << a;
        res_handler.exponentiation(res.str());
    }
    else
    {
        std::stringstream res;
        res << pow(a, b);
        res_handler.exponentiation(res.str());
    }
}

int main()
{
    //Declare variables
    double a, b;
    char function;
    std::string line;

    while (true)
    {
        misc.ClearScreen();
        std::getline(std::cin, line);

        //Check if the input is empty and ignore
        if (line.empty())
        {
            continue;
        }
        //Check if the input is either 'q' or 'Q' and break loop
        else if (line[0] == 'q' || line[0] == 'Q')
        {
            break;
        }
        //Else if everything is OK extract data
        else
        {
            std::istringstream inStream(line);
            inStream >> a;
            inStream >> function;
            inStream >> b;

            //Check for bad input and print error
            if (!inStream || function != '+' && function != '-' && function != '*' &&     function != '/' && function != '^')
            {
                std::cerr << "\"" << line << "\" is invalid input";
            }
        }

        //Check what the user wants to do
        switch (function)
        {
        case '+': std::cout << math.addition(a, b); break;
        case '-': std::cout << math.subtraction(a, b); break;
        case '*': std::cout << math.multiplication(a, b); break;
        case '/': math.division(a, b); break;
        case '^': math.exponentiation(a, b); break;
        }
        misc.Pause();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The request for a library is not on-topic here, nor is it anywhere on SE.  You may just have to search for something yourself and try to implement it here.

Answer (score 1):

#### The singleton pattern:

Your classes `Math_Functions`, `Results_Handler` and `Miscellaneous` seem like an attempt at the *singleton pattern* (see [**1**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern) and [**2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)). Your approach of declaring a global instance of each class is also valid, but has a few drawback and is not very conventional.

Since your classes hold no member data and the class is really just serving as a name space for the functions, I would use an actual `namespace` instead and don't even bother with a full-blown singleton implementation in this case. Example:

```
namespace math
{
    double addition(double, double);
    double subtraction(double, double);
    double multiplication(double, double);
    void division(double, double);
    void exponentiation(double, double);
} // namespace
```

Then to access each function you now have to use the `::` (namespace resolution) operator: `math::addition(a, b);`

#### Miscellaneous tips:

- Keep parameter names in function prototypes. This adds to the code documentation.
- Be consistent with your naming convention. You have both `PascalCase` and `camelCase` names for functions/methods. Choose one and use it consistently.
- Functions from `<cmath>`, such as `pow()`, should be accessed using the fully qualified name with the `std::` prefix. I.e.: `std::pow()`.
- Consider splitting your project in a few separate source files. There is quite a bit of code here already to be kept all in the same source file. You should ideally place each class in its own `.cpp/.h` pair.
- Returning zero at the end of `main` is optional. If you don't do it explicitly, the compiler will default to a `return 0`.

Comment: I really want to separate the code in different files, but the problem is I don't know how (yet). I can include other `.cpp` files in the main, but this way it doesn't make much sense to me. Thanks for the guidelines :)

Comment: @skorpi7478, Well, take a look at how to do that in your IDE/compiler. You will then have the class implementation in a .CPP file and the declaration in a header file (.H); Then you include the .H in your other sources files, such as in main.cpp.